# Catastrophic Error when Clearing a ListBox C# UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, listbox

When the program runs it populates a listBox (lstBox) from an XML file.
I then have code to delete an element or contact from an xml file and I want to also remove that entry from my listBox. I am getting catastrophic failure error when I try to remove it via lstBox.Items.Clear() or RemoveAt. This is apparently because I have an item source as data binding.

This explains what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

Here is all the code in paste bin.

```
https://pastebin.com/CFs21njZ
```

What I believe to be the relevant methods are

```
public async void loadContacts()
        {

            StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Contacts.xml");
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(file.Path);
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.Name.Equals("ID") && (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element))
                {
                    lstd.Add(xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString());
                }
            }
            DataContext = this;
            xmlReader.Dispose();
        }
```

And

```
private async void btnDeleteContact_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Contacts.xml");
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file.Path);
            if (lstBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                xdoc.Element("Contacts")
                    .Elements("Contact")
                    .Where(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == lstBox.SelectedItem.ToString()).Remove();
                //lstBox.SelectedIndex = -1; 
                updateXMLFile(xdoc);

                //lstBox.Items.Clear();   //Causing catastrophic error               

                loadContacts();
            }
        }
```

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you bound the ListBox.ItemSource property to 'myList', why not doing
    myList.Clear();

Interacting with both Items and ItemSource property can and will throw exceptions